# Where does zappa upload environment variables to?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, environment-variables, zappa

**tl;dr**

Environment variables set in a `zappa_settings.json` don't upload as environment variables to AWS Lambda. Where do they go?

**ts;wm**

I have a Lambda function configured, deployed and managed using the Zappa framework. In the `zappa_settings.json` I have set a number of environment variables. These variables are definitely present as my application successfully runs however, when trying to inspect the Lambda function environment variables in the console or AWS CLI I see no environment variables have been uploaded to the Lambda function itself.

Extract from zappa_settings.json:

```
{
  "stage-dev": {
    "app_function": "project.app",
    "project_name": "my-project",
    "runtime": "python3.7",
    "s3_bucket": "my-project-zappa",
    "slim_handler": true,
    "environment_variables": {
      "SECRET": "mysecretvalue"
    }
  }
}
```

Output of `aws lambda get-function-configuration --function-name my-project-stage-dev`:

```
{
  "Configuration": {
    "FunctionName": "my-project-stage-dev",
    "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:000000000000:function:my-project-stage-dev",
    "Runtime": "python3.7",
    "Role": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/lambda-execution-role",
    "Handler": "handler.lambda_handler",
    "CodeSize": 12333025,
    "Description": "Zappa Deployment",
    "Timeout": 30,
    "MemorySize": 512,
    "LastModified": "...",
    "CodeSha256": "...",
    "Version": "$LATEST",
    "TracingConfig": {
      "Mode": "PassThrough"
    },
    "RevisionId": "..."
  },
  "Code": {
    "RepositoryType": "S3",
    "Location": "..."
  }
}
```

`Environment` is absent from the output despite being included in the zappa_settings and the AWS documentation indicating it should be included if present, this is confirmed by checking in the console. I want to know where zappa is uploading the environment variables to, and if possible why it is doing so over using Lambda's in-built environment?

AWS CLI docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/get-function-configuration.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`environment_variables`](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#local-environment-variables) are saved in *zappa_settings.py* when creating a package for deployment (run `zappa package STAGE` and explore the archive) and are then dynamically set as environment variables by modifying `os.environ` in *handler.py*.

To set native AWS variables you need to use [`aws_environment_variables`](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#remote-aws-environment-variables).

Comment: ‍♂️ Can't believe I missed that. Thanks for the link and the explanation.